# Convert 2022-04-20T17:00:00.000Z to timepicker format

Tags: reactjs, antd

I have a value like 2022-04-20T17:00:00.000Z, I want to convert it like as in image which is only accepts in antd timepicker,
[image]

How to convert?

Answer (score 0):

Install the `moment` library:

`npm install moment`

Then import it into your project

`import moment from "moment"`

use it to format your date

`const momentDate = moment("2022-04-20T17:00:00.000Z")`

Comment: date.clone is not a function errror occurs

Answer (score 0):

You can use the moment for this.

```
const date = "2022-04-20T17:00:00.000Z";
const timePickerMomentObj = moment(date);
```

For more datils, you can [visit moment document](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/)

Comment: date.clone is not a function erro occurs

Comment: @LeyaVarghese Can you please share a code snippet to show how you have used it?

Answer (score 0):

you can simply `new Date()`

```
new Date('2022-04-20T17:00:00.000Z');
```

like this to convert given timestamp into required format

then you can also extract only the part you want

```
var d = new Date('2022-04-20T17:00:00.000Z');
console.log(d.getUTCHours()); // Hours
console.log(d.getUTCMinutes()); //Minutes
console.log(d.getUTCSeconds()); //Seconds
```